# Under which conditions there exists a solution in linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, duality-theorems

I am having some troubles with an exercise from "Finite dimensional vector spaces" by Halmos. I am not sure if my proof is correct or if my answer is what the author asked for. Thanks for any help!

> Suppose that $m < n$ and that $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ are linear functionals on an $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{V}$. Under what conditions on the scalars $\alpha_{1}, \dots, \alpha_{m}$ is it true that there exists a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{V}$ such that $y_{j}(x) = \alpha_{j}$ for $j = 1, \dots, m$? What does this result say about the solutions of linear equations?

We assume without loss of generality that at least two vectors of $y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}$ are linearly dependent. More precisely there exists a $k, l \leq m$ and $c \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $y_{k}(x_{0}) = cy_{l}(x_{0})$ with $k \neq l$. Now we can write $y_{k}(x_{0}) - cy_{l}(x_{0}) = \alpha_{k} - c\alpha_{l} = 0$. From that we can state that such a vector $x$ in $\mathbb{V}$ exists under the condition that there does exist such a $c \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $\alpha_{k} = c\alpha_{l}$ if $y_{k}$ and $y_{l}$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: Just curious, what do $\mathbb K$ and $y_j(x)$ mean?

Comment: By $\mathbb{K}$ I mean the field which is related to the given vector space and by $y_{j}(x)$ I mean a linear functional ($\mathbb{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is loss of generality in your assumption. For example the sum of all may vanish while pairwise they are independent.

You need to find the kernel of the map $\Lambda: c\in {\Bbb C}^m \mapsto \sum_j c_j y_j$. Then clearly if $c\in \ker \Lambda$, a solution to $y_j(x)=\alpha_j$ must verify:
$$ 0=\sum_j c_j y_j(x)= \sum_j c_j \alpha_j$$ 
So $\alpha$ should be orthogonal to the kernel of $\Lambda$. This happens also to be a sufficient condition. If $\Lambda^* : x\in V \mapsto (y_1(x),\ldots, y_m(x)) \in {\Bbb C}^m$ denotes the dual map to $\Lambda$ then a theorem from (finite dimensional) linear analysis states that 
$$ \mbox{Im } \Lambda^* = (\ker \Lambda)^T$$
and this translates into the above-mentioned condition.

Comment: I see where my assumption was wrong. $c$ would be the solution in your case and you are looking with $\ker \Lambda$ at the solutions which evaluate to zero. I am not really familiar with the term "orthogonal" though. Can it be described more basic?

Comment: An explicit formulation may enhance comprehension? If e.g. in dim 3, $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$  we consider $y_1(x)=x_1$, $y_2(x)=x_2$ and $y_3(x)=x_1+x_2$ then they are not independent, $y_1+y_2-y_3$ is identically zero, or $\Lambda(c)=\Lambda((1,1,-1)=0 \in V'$ in my notation. If $\alpha$ is in a solution to the equation then necessarily $<c,\alpha>=\alpha_1+\alpha_2-\alpha_3=0$ or else for sure there can be no solution (try to write things down). This is not 'orthogonality' in the usual sense because it is between objects living in different spaces.

Comment: Ok thanks! Makes sense now.